# Display a popup only once per user (localStorage or DB)

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, popup

I have an Angular web app and I want to display a popup only once per user. From my research the two ways to do this are: storing the data in browser memory or storing it in the DB.

With storing it in browser memory, a user could use a different browser or clear their memory so I don't think that is a good option. Is storing in the DB the best/recommended way to do this?

Comment: Depends on your use case. If you want them to see it again when they clear their browser data then use local storage. If you want to show it to them once and only once, you would *have* to store that boolean value in a db, probably as a field on the user itself.

Comment: This isn't the right community to ask a non-code related question as this is more of an architecture topic. Please read over https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. But to answer your question, if this user has to login first it's the logical decision to store it in the database so the pop-up will always only show 1 time per user. otherwise if they use a different device it will show again.